# angular nested directive pass value from child

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following code, but I couldn't make to work, I want to pass a simple string to "parent" directive from "child" directive.  Here is http://jsfiddle.net/fpax1hx7/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app=myApp>
  <div ng-controller=MyCtrl>
    <directive1></directive1>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { }])
.directive('directive1', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { stringtest: '=' },
    template: '<directive2 stringtest="stringTest"></directive2>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
      console.log(scope.stringTest);
    }

  }
})
.directive('directive2', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: { stringTest: '=' },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
        scope.stringtest="This is a Test";
      }
   }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo. You are using `stringtest` instead of `stringTest` and you are not passing any model to `directive1`

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    console.log('from controller');
  }])
  .directive('directive1', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        stringTest: '='
      },
      template: '<directive2 string-test="stringTest"></directive2>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('from directive1');
        console.log('string test from directive 1:' + scope.stringTest);
        scope.$watch('stringTest', function(nv, ov) {
          if (nv !== ov) {
            console.log('string test from directive 1 after directive2 scope binded:' + scope.stringTest);
          }
        });
      }

    }
  })
  .directive('directive2', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        stringTest: '='
      },
      link: {
        pre: function(scope) {
          scope.stringTest = "This is a Test";
        },
        post: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log('from directive2');
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app=myApp>
  <div ng-controller=MyCtrl>
    <directive1 string-test="sample"></directive1>
    {{sample}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for you reply, can I put alert stringTest inside directive1 and it still works?

Comment: updated the code. You can see the order of execution and how the directive scopes binding works. if you get the answer you expected, please mark this as resolve :)

Comment: It work on mine but I have to set the third parameter $watch to true, but it also gives me "Illegal invocation" error.